# No notification on a remote computer with notify-send

Tags: linux, ssh, notifications

I can't send a notification with `notify-send` over `ssh`, even though I have no problem launching other GUI programs from the same `ssh` connection

The command I use is:

```
ssh -X user@remote "DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send this is a test"
```

There's no problem when I launch other programs (`Steam`, `GVim`, etc) with this method.

In fact, `notify-send` works fine if I try to do it on the remote computer itself.

I'm trying to do this on an `ArchLinux` with `libnotify 0.7.6`